# MySQL: Add constraint if not exists

Tags: mysql, constraints

In my create script for my database create script looking something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rabbits`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `main_page_id` INT UNSIGNED COMMENT 'What page is the main one',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `main_page_id` (`main_page_id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rabbit_pages`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `rabbit_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `content` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `rabbit_id` (`rabbit_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_rabbits_pages` FOREIGN KEY (`rabbit_id`) REFERENCES `rabbits` (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `rabbits`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rabbits_main_page` FOREIGN KEY (`main_page_id`) REFERENCES `rabbit_pages` (`id`);
```

This runs fine the first time, but if I run it again it fails on the last line there with "Duplicate key on write or update".

Is there a way I can do sort of a `ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS` or something like that? Like I can do with the `CREATE TABLE` query?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Interesting question. You may want to disable foreign keys before you call your `CREATE TABLE` statements and enable them afterwards. This will allow you to define the foreign keys directly in the `CREATE TABLE` DDL:

Example:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rabbits` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `main_page_id` INT UNSIGNED COMMENT 'What page is the main one',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `main_page_id` (`main_page_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_rabbits_main_page` FOREIGN KEY (`main_page_id`) REFERENCES `rabbit_pages` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rabbit_pages` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `rabbit_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `content` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `rabbit_id` (`rabbit_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_rabbits_pages` FOREIGN KEY (`rabbit_id`) REFERENCES `rabbits` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Test case:

```
INSERT INTO rabbits (name, main_page_id) VALUES ('bobby', NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

INSERT INTO rabbit_pages (rabbit_id, title, content) VALUES (1, 'My Main Page', 'Hello');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM rabbits;
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | name  | main_page_id |
+----+-------+--------------+
|  1 | bobby | NULL         |
+----+-------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM rabbit_pages;
+----+-----------+--------------+---------+
| id | rabbit_id | title        | content |
+----+-----------+--------------+---------+
|  1 |         1 | My Main Page | Hello   |
+----+-----------+--------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

UPDATE rabbits SET main_page_id = 2 WHERE id = 1;
ERROR 1452 (23000): A foreign key constraint fails

UPDATE rabbits SET main_page_id = 1 WHERE id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

UPDATE rabbit_pages SET rabbit_id = 2 WHERE id = 1;
ERROR 1452 (23000): A foreign key constraint fails
```

Comment: Hm, I thought I had to create table A, create table B with B->A and then add A->B because the constraint would fail if a table does not exist yet... weird... will try this out ASAP :p

Comment: @Svish: It would, unless you have that `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` at the top. That's the trick. We're then setting it back to `1` at the end.

Comment: I'm having this problem too, and I will try to update my script to use  FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS. What would happen on an error tough, if I run `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;` with an invalid foreign key?

Comment: In all honesty I might create a store procedure that checks if the FK exists from the information schema and adds the constraints only if necessary. Then drop the store procedure.

Answer (score 33):

MariaDB supports this syntax in [10.0.2 or later](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-table/):

```
ALTER TABLE `rabbits`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rabbits_main_page` FOREIGN KEY IF NOT EXISTS
(`main_page_id`) REFERENCES `rabbit_pages` (`id`);
```

Comment: Dang, mariadb only.

Comment: I've found that this doesn't work for me on MariaDB 10.3. There is no complaint about the syntax, but re-running the same `ALTER` statement still results in a failure with the error message mentioned in the question. In my case, there were other alterations to the table at the same time as the `ADD CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY` so that may have been the problem.

Answer (score 30):

The `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` is a great tools but if your need to know how to do this without dropping and recreating your tables. You can use a `SELECT` statement ON `information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` to determine if the foreign key exists:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL 
    FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE
        CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND
        CONSTRAINT_NAME   = 'fk_rabbits_main_page' AND
        CONSTRAINT_TYPE   = 'FOREIGN KEY'
)
THEN
    ALTER TABLE `rabbits`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rabbits_main_page`
    FOREIGN KEY (`main_page_id`)
    REFERENCES `rabbit_pages` (`id`);
END IF
```

Comment: This is very useful and defensive i like it

Comment: This solution looks like it would work, but generates the following error (if you use it in place of ALTER TABLE in the original SQL statement posted by OP):

`[ERROR in query 3] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE
     ' at line 1
[ERROR in query 4] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 1`

Comment: @jsdalton I think this syntax only works inside a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-MariaDB, this worked for me:

```
SET @dbname = DATABASE();
SET @tablename = "my_table";
SET @constraintname = "my_constraint_name";
SET @columnname = "my_column";
SET @othertablename = "other_table";
SET @othercolumnname = "other_column_name";
SET @deleteaction = "CASCADE";
SET @updateaction = "RESTRICT";
SET @preparedStatement = (SELECT IF(
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE
      (table_name = @tablename)
      AND (table_schema = @dbname)
      AND (constraint_name = @constraintname)
  ) > 0,
  "SELECT 1",
  CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",@tablename,
    " ADD CONSTRAINT ",@constraintname,
    " FOREIGN KEY(",@columnname,")
      REFERENCES ",@othertablename,"(",@othercolumnname,")
      ON DELETE ",@deleteaction,
    " ON UPDATE ",@updateaction)));
PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement;
EXECUTE alterIfNotExists;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;
```

This is a solution, is made from a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31989541/3589448

Add parameters as needed. @deleteaction and @updateaction can have: "RESTRICT", "CASCADE", "SET NULL" or "NO ACTION".