# MySql IF statement in query

Tags: mysql, constraints

I just finished picking up my jaw off the floor after learning that you can't use an IF statement in a query in MySql. How can anyone get *anything* done without an IF statement?!

What I'm trying to do is write a DML script that adds a constraint to a table, if it doesn't exist. Something like this:

```
if (select count(*) from information_schema.table_constraints
    where constraint_name='fk_user_user_status') = 0
then
    alter table `user`
        add constraint fk_user_user_status foreign key (status_id)
            references user_status(id);
end if;
```

How would one do this in MySql?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919226/mysql-add-constraint-if-not-exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procedural batch, but within the below, a proc is created and dropped after the operation completes.

```
delimiter $$

drop procedure if exists tmp_add_fk $$

create procedure tmp_add_fk()
begin
if (select count(*) from information_schema.table_constraints
    where constraint_name='fk_user_user_status') = 0
then
    alter table `user`
        add constraint fk_user_user_status foreign key (status_id)
            references user_status(id);
end if;
end$$

delimiter ;

call tmp_add_fk;

drop procedure tmp_add_fk;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, Richard! I was just thinking about doing the same. One question, though: what are those $$'s and delimiters for?

Comment: @alekop You could almost get away without changing the delimiter since the proc finishes in one statement. But it allows you to have multi-statement procs (containing `;`) which would otherwise end the proc definition as soon as it sees `;`. e.g. `delimiter $$` changes it so that statements only stop at `$$`.

Comment: Got it, thanks! This is only necessary when working through the `mysql` shell.

Answer (score 3):

You can only run IF statements in stored procedures and functions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html

If you are executing standard scripts, then IF statements only work with SELECT queries.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if