# ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS doesn't work for me

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to test [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919226/mysql-add-constraint-if-not-exists) solution of ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS, but I get an error with my code :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE
                   CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'mydatabase' AND
                   CONSTRAINT_NAME   = 'tb_uq') THEN
   ALTER TABLE `scrape_xpaths` ADD CONSTRAINT `tb_uq` UNIQUE (`LinkCaption`);
END IF
```

I get a check syntax error.

Also this doesn't work:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS) THEN

END IF
```

Same error.

Constraint name 'tb_uq' exists because commands :

```
SELECT NULL FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

work and return all constraints and tb_uq is one of them. What am I doing wrong?

This is how I add the constraint the first time. Second time fails of course :

```
ALTER TABLE `mydatabase`.tablename ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (LinkCaption);
```

Also the code below fails with the same error :

```
if (true)
begin

end else
begin

end
```

Comment: is the CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA mydatabase not dbo? could you show the line from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS you are trying to match?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` gives me # CONSTRAINT_CATALOG, CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_TYPE
**'def', 'mydatabase', 'tb_uq', 'mydatabase', 'scrape_information', 'UNIQUE'** on the line I'm trying to match

Comment: Right is the error you are getting 'Incorrect syntax near 'if'.'? you don't need the if on End if

Comment: That's the error I'm getting. It fails without the if on End if also. Same error : `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS) THEN
  
END ` fails also

Comment: Sorry just noticed the Then as well sql If Syntax is If [Condition] Begin End

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. So `SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='mydatabase' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME='tb_uq' AND TABLE_NAME='scrape_information';` returns the correct row. BUT, `if exists (SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='mydatabase' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME='tb_uq' AND TABLE_NAME='scrape_information')
begin
end else
begin
end` gives me the same error

Comment: as there is nothing in your begin and end blocks you will get an error if exists (SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='mydatabase' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME='tb_uq' AND TABLE_NAME='scrape_information') 
begin 
 print 'run'
end else 
begin 
print 'dont run' 
end runs and doesnt give an error for me

Comment: I'm using MSQLWorkbench , would that be the pb?

Comment: Ok I have installed MySQL on a VM and had a look, by the looks of it you cant run an if like this in workbench. The If would need to be in a select not as a function on its own. All i could find is people saying try anyway and handle the error